# superscript and subscript in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Is there any method for superscript and subscript just like html tag ?
For eg. 
 My form has some component like textfield, Table etc. I want to put some variable name in my table like **Tin** where *in* should be a subscript and it should look like T<sub>in</sub>

I tried to set style and margin but that was not effective at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin support for that in Codename One, we hope to provide richer text tools in the near future but right not some developers just embed a `WebBrowser` component and use HTML if they have a lot of rich text.